# Drupal Commerce custom checkout pane state not working as expected

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I'm attempting to add a conditionally displayed fieldset in a custom checkout pane. The fieldset is always displayed regardless of the state, unlike on a standard form.

For example, in the code below I want the "hungry_fields" fieldset displayed based on the value of the "hungry" radio button.

```
function hungry_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

  $pane_form['hungry'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array('yes' => t('Yes'), 'no' => t('No')),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => t('I am hungry')
  );

  $pane_form['hungry_fields'] = array(
    '#title' => 'Hungry',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="hungry"]' => array('value' => 'yes'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $pane_form;

}
```

I'm new to Drupal Commerce so it's entirely possible I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using a form callback with drupal_get_form() instead of adding the fields to the array directly.

For example:

```
function hungry_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {

  $pane_form['form'] = drupal_get_form('hungry_form');

}

function hungry_form($form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}
```

Using this method the forms work properly.